# RoboBrowser submit form response status 500

Tags: python, python-requests, mechanize, mechanize-python, robobrowser

I'm trying to login in Quora using robobrowser and i wrote this script

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser(
    history=True,
    user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/48.0.2564.82 Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36'
)

login_url = 'https://www.quora.com/'

browser.open(login_url)

# browser.find(class_="remember_me").extract()

form = browser.get_form(class_="inline_login_form")

form['email'].value = 'myemail@gmail.com'
form['password'].value = <mypass>

browser.submit_form(form)

print browser.response.status_code
```

I'm able to get login form and insert values(email and pass). once i submit the form using `browser.submit_form`, it doesn't raises any error/exception  but when i print status code it says 500. I'm not able to understand where am I making mistake.

Comment: Looks like a scraping prevention method by Quora.